# What are good resources for FIFA 12?

Tags: fifa-12

For Starcraft you have http://blip.tv/day9tv or http://www.teamliquid.net/ and for Street Fighter you have http://crosscounter.tv/ or http://shoryuken.com/ . Is there a good site for FIFA 12 that discusses strategies, tutorials, replays etc.?

I searched for basic terms like fifa, tutorial, replays, strategies etc. but the sites I found were either very basic, had no community or were just old.

So the things I look for are:

- strategies (offensive/defensive)
- tutorials (corner, free-kick etc.)
- replays / videos of good players
- commentaries beyond just stating the obvious
- solid community

Comment: You could help make http://gaming.stackexchange.com a good resource for it. Just an idea, but start posting questions about the strategies and things you are looking for and you might get some help.

Comment: I would like to ask the same question but in regards to NHL 12 however it doesnt even have its own tag

Comment: @Beef if you add a question and can't add the tag because of your level, someone will likely get it added for you. Please do add them.

Comment: @Blake alright thanks, once I come across a good specific question I will throw it on here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[FIFA Encyclopedia](http://www.fifaencyclopedia.com) seems to be a good resource.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube videos usually have instructions or player strategies which people post and talk you through them as their setting things up. Might not be much help but it's a start.